# VMWare Server 2 Web Interface not loading

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-server

I am having an issue with VMWare Server 2 running on a Windows SBS 2008 host.

I can browse to https://server:8333/ and if I view source I can see that the page has loaded, but the redirection and browsing directly to https://server:8333/ui/ never finishes loading - just continually tries to load the page.

I'm not sure what logs to check or where I should go from here, but I need to get more VMs running on this server - any ideas?

Cheers,

Sam

Comment: Looks like we're just gonna roll a ESXi server, thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering the same problem for a long time and most of these hints (CTRL-R or vmware restart) worked for me for long. But some time ago i found a thread on the official vmware forum there people tracked down the problem to some SSL-protocol-wiredness between vmware-webui and current webbrowsers.

To cut things short, you must activate SSLv2 Mode on your webbrowser and maybe reload the webui via CTRL-R. You can get detailed instructions about this workaround on my Blog.

http://www.rootz.de/2010/05/vmware-2-x-kein-zugriff-auf-die-weboberflache-moglich-loading/

(its written in german but maybe the screenshots are helpful)

Comment: Thanks for your response, however we ditched the VMware server and are now running an ESXi server.

Answer (score 0):

Have seen similar behaviour on Centos 5 as well. What we do is to restart the service that listens on port 8333. This takes care of the problem.

There is also command line API for VMWare server - try command 'vmrun'

Comment: Thanks - I had a look at vmrun and could see functions for stopping and starting VMs etc, but no sort of service that could give me access back into the Web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly the command line API doesn't work when the webservice is not running correctly.

The logs are usually in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\VMware\VMware Server` and in the individual virtual machine folders.  These are usually quite helpful.

I have found that a problem with vmware server or with an individual machine can stop the interface from working.

Another thing that you might want to check is that I had an SSL handshake error under firefox after installing the console plugin, it seems far happier when you use IE.

Comment: I had a look at this but wasn't able to find anything obvious, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

use the non ssl http://localhost:8222

this will allow you to connect to it via non ssl and no certificate issues ir ssl 2.0 configs in firefox